# Как ограничить доступ по паролю к порту c помощью nginx?

Tags: nginx, auth, безопасность

По адресу `domain.ru:1234` запускается один сервис.

Как настроить доступ по паролю в *nginx* для соединений на этот адрес?

Для каталогов знаю, а вот с портом, что-то не нашел.

Comment: а этот порт слушает `nginx`?

Comment: Да, там вебсервис. location надо как-то написать.

Comment: во-первых, location там, скорее всего есть. но в данном случае несущественно: в область применения директивы *auth_basic* входят [не только *location*, но и *server*, и вообще *http*](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html). так что вы можете добавить две строчки в секцию *server* и настроить файл с паролями.

Answer (score 1):

[Модуль ngx_http_auth_basic_module позволяет ограничить доступ к ресурсам с проверкой имени и пароля пользователя по протоколу “HTTP Basic Authentication”](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html)

> Синтаксис:    auth_basic строка | off;
>
> Контекст: http, **server**, location, limit_except

Comment: Попробовал, получается в конфиге будет 2 директивы server, одна на 80 порт, другая на 1234, nginx выдает ошибку, что это недопустимо.

Comment: @Magi я уверен, что ты прочёл русскоязычную документацию nginx. Если нет - начинай отсюда http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html И покажи свой конфиг

Comment: Вторую директиву добавил, но появилось вот такое. На порту 1234 демон доступ к которому и нужно ограничить по паролю..
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:1234 failed (48: Address already in use)

Comment: Значит этот порт кто-то случает. Значит этого кого-то нужно научить слушать другой порт, на 1234 порт повесить nginx на котором выполнять авторизацию и в случае успеха проксировать запрос на имярека.